# Using JSON as a service in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs

I realise there are a few answers to this question on here, but I just can't seem to get them working with my set up. This is a Plunker of what I am trying achieve (not my own work): http://plnkr.co/edit/Ofq7Md8udEnIhAPF1NgL?p=preview

Currently, I have this for my index.html file:

```
<body ng-app="HomeCourtArenaApp">

    <div class="container" ng-view></div>

    <script src="components/angular/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="components/require/require.js"></script>
    <script src="components/angular/angular-resource.js"></script>

    <script src="scripts/services/data.js"></script>
    <script src="scripts/app.js"></script>

</body>
```

To register the components, I have defined them in the karma.conf.js file:

```
files = [
  JASMINE,
  JASMINE_ADAPTER,
  'app/components/angular/angular.js',
  'app/components/angular/angular-resource.js',
  'app/components/angular-mocks/angular-mocks.js',
  'app/scripts/*.js',
  'app/scripts/**/*.js',
  'test/mock/**/*.js',
  'test/spec/**/*.js'
];
```

To then create the service, I use the same technique that seems to be documented online in most examples:

```
'use strict';

angular.module('jsonData', ['ngResource'])
.factory('jsonData', function($resource) {
  return $resource('data/shoe3Dconfig.js');
});
```

Where an error seems to be triggered is when I try to define the service in my 'app' variable, where adding the service name stops the content loading ['jsonData']:

'use strict';

```
var app = angular.module('HomeCourtArenaApp', ['jsonData']);

app.config(function ($routeProvider) {
  $routeProvider
    .when('/', {
      templateUrl: 'views/main.html',
      controller: 'MainCtrl'
    })
    .otherwise({
      redirectTo: '/'
    });
});
```

I would share my views and controllers also, but before I can even use the JSON data in my template, there are an unearthly amount of errors to deal with:

```
Uncaught Error: Module name "path" has not been loaded yet for context: _. Use require([])

Uncaught Error: Mismatched anonymous define() module: function () {
    return getStyleProperty;
  }

Uncaught Error: No module: ngResource
```

There are some other errors also, but these seem to be mainly because the scripts further up the DOM are stopping them loading correctly. Any help would be great!

Comment: You've named your module and factory the same, 'jsonData'. The example you have posted has a casing difference which you would also need. Or give the service/module a different name so you don't confuse the two. It would also be good to have a plunker of your (non-working) code.

Comment: I have made a basic Plunker, though as I can't see the console in Plunker, it is a bit hard to tell if this is exact: http://plnkr.co/edit/uPE78I0m90jjmpBL50LK?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

you could try this :

the app.js:

```
angular.module('HomeCourtArenaApp', ['HomeCourtArenaApp.services', 'HomeCourtArenaApp.controllers']).
    config(['$routeProvider', ($routeProvider) {
        $routeProvider.when('/', { templateUrl: 'views/main.html', controller: 'MainCtrl' });
        $routeProvider.otherwise({ redirectTo: '/'});
}]);

angular.module('HomeCourtArenaApp.services', ['ngResource']).
    factory('JsonData', function($resource){
    return $resource('data/shoe3Dconfig.js');
});

angular.module('HomeCourtArenaApp.controllers', []).
controller('MainCtrl', ['$scope', 'JsonData', function($scope, JsonData) {
    $scope.objs = JsonData.query();
        console.log(objs);
    }
}]);
```

and this is not necessary to load the datas in the html

```
<script src="scripts/services/data.js"></script>
```

Comment: I have tried this, but still throws up the same errors. Does require.js need to be a server and clientside module to work?

Answer (score 0):

This edited plunker http://plnkr.co/edit/33qW5VRnQVrHWFlp16kz?p=preview should get you further along the way.

You need to specify the module (jsonData) that you want in your app as a dependency. There is currently no name displayed since your data does not have a name property.

Your JSON service module definition named as 'jsonData'

```
angular.module('jsonData', ['ngResource'])
```

This module defines a service provider (factory) 'jsonService'

```
.factory('jsonService', function($resource) {
```

You list the 'jsonData' module as a dependency for your module so that you can access anything defined in there

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', ['jsonData']);
```

You then use Angular's Dependency Injection to request an instance of jsonService

```
app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope, jsonService) {
```

Note that if you "production-ise" this and minify your JS, you will need to configure the DI code. I will leave that to you to find in the Angular docs.

Does this explain things a bit more?

And you can get the console in plunker by opening the developer tools in your browser.

Comment: Can you explain why you call the module and service both jsonData, then instantiate this with jsonService in the controller? There is a 'name' in the data.js file, how come it won't pull that one through?

Comment: ok, thanks for your help. Still too many console errors to even get this running. Think I am going to something a little simpler and return to this!

Comment: The "name" property in your case is on each element, not the whole data. That is the difference compared to the working plunker.